# Открытие форм Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть три форм WinForms. `Form2` и `Form3` открываются из первой формы, вот мне нужно `Form2` показать пользователю уже открытый экземпляр `Form3`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что для вас означает слово «открывалась»?

Comment: попробую объяснить вот  так, переход между формами при нажатии `button`

Comment: Всё равно не совсем понятно. У вас форма уже создана и показана, и вы хотите просто вынести её из фона на передний план, или у вас формы ещё нет, и вы хотите её создать и показать?

Comment: нужно вынести её из фона на передний план

Comment: Попробуйте `form3.Activate()`. При этом у `Form2` должна быть, понятно, ссылка на `Form3`

Comment: `form3.Activate()` вообще не понимает

Comment: А `form3.BringToFront()`?